# imagejpeg() permission problems

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

Im trying to create thumbnails using gd library and am using the `imagejpeg()` function. The output then shows the following error

> Warning: imagejpeg()
>   [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open
>   '/var/www/html/yahoo/thumbs/1136.jpg'
>   for writing: Permission denied in
>   /var/www/html/yahoo/Thumbnail.php on
>   line 56

I have set full 777 permissions on the thumbs folder, is there something else that could be causing this, or am i missing something here.

thanks :)

Ive tried creating the file with fopen and am getting the same issue.. fopen returns the following warning:

```
Warning: fopen(/var/www/html/yahoo/thumbs/1176.jpg) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/yahoo/Thumbnail.php on line 56 can't open file
```

Comment: Try creating the file first using `fopen()`.

Comment: Mind the umask: http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php

Comment: Could CHOWN be a problem. Like is the PHP user the same user as your FTP user.

Comment: Is there a 1136.jpg file already? If there is, you'd need write permissions on the file itself to be able to overwrite it with a new one.

Comment: no its not there, so do i need to create the file first with fopen, and set the permissions on it? If so, what access should i give

Comment: Ive tried creating the file with fopen and am getting the same issue.. fopen returns the same warning: Warning: fopen(/var/www/html/yahoo/thumbs/1176.jpg) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/yahoo/Thumbnail.php on line 56
can't open file

Comment: http://serverfault.com/search?q=centos+httpd+selinux

Comment: are you suggesting i post the question on serverfault?

Comment: No. Although flagging it to be moved to Server Fault by a mod is an option.

Comment: Are you running in safemode? Does the user the server is running have access to that path, have you got the path right, etc.

Comment: how do i make sure the user has access to that path?

Comment: and yeap, im not in safe mode, the dir is 777 and i have the right path... the directory is owned by the user using the system.. does that mean the user has access to the path... im really lost here, does anyone know how i can progress. :-)

Comment: hmm .. i just did echo `whoami`; from my php script and it outputted apache. ??? so i changed the owner of the directory to apache but it still doesnt work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELinux is preventing HTTPd from writing into that directory. Use `chcon` to change the file context of `/var/www/html/yahoo/thumbs/` to `httpd_sys_rw_content_t`, and if that lets it work then use `semanage` to make it permanent.

Comment: thanks it worked, i ran the following:

semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/html/yahoo/thumbs'

restorecon -v '/var/www/html/yahoo/thumbs'

Comment: The `restorecon -v '/var/www/html/yahoo/thumbs'` caused a 'bad option' error, but without it it worked fine

Comment: I have the same issue and i'm not able to solve it. Could you explain me more?